# drupal views filter automatically on node id

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I would like to use a view to display some images on a node page.
So i created a bloc view showing the images in a nice slider but this shows all the images of all the node's.

I was wondering if there was a way to automatically filter out only the images that belong to the node that's currently being displayed.
I've read something about arguments but I don't really see how I can use them to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an argument of "Node: NID." For the "Action to take if argument is not present:" setting, select "Provide default argument", then "Node ID from URL."